# display woocommerce related products under product gallery

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I removed related products from single product

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );
```

now I want to display related products under product image gallery. Here is product gallery code.

```
/*******Single Product ********/
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'show_product_thumbnails', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'show_product_images', 10 );

function show_product_thumbnails(){
    global $post, $product, $woocommerce;

    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
    $count_gallery  = count($attachment_ids);

    echo '<div class="thumbnails" id="gallery">';

    if ( $attachment_ids ) {
        echo '<div class="main-slider" style="width:85%; float:right;position: relative;">'
            echo '<div class="slider slider-for">';
                foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
                    $totem_single_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'shop_single', true );
                    $image_link         = $totem_single_image[0];
                    $main_image_link    = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
                    $image_title        = esc_attr( get_the_title( $attachment_id ) );
                    $image              = wp_get_attachment_image( 
                        $attachment_id, 
                        apply_filters( 'single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ),
                        0,
                        $attr = array(
                            'title' => $image_title,
                            'alt'   => $image_title
                        )
                    );

                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="elevatezoom-gallery" title="%s"><img class="lily_zoom" src="%s" alt="%s" data-zoom-image="%s"></a>', $main_image_link, $image_caption, $image_link, $image_title, $main_image_link), $attachment_id, $post->ID );  
                }
            echo '</div>';
        echo'</div>';

        echo '<div class="pagination" style="width:13%; display:block;">';
            echo '<div class="slider slider-nav" role="toolbar">';
                foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
                    $totem_single_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'medium', true );
                    $image_link         = $totem_single_image[0];
                    $main_image_link    = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
                    $image_title        = esc_attr( get_the_title( $attachment_id ) );
                    $image              = wp_get_attachment_image( 
                        $attachment_id, 
                        apply_filters( 'single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ), 
                        0, 
                        $attr = array(
                            'title' => $image_title,
                            'alt'   => $image_title
                        )
                    );

                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s"></a>', $image_link,$image_title), $attachment_id, $post->ID );  
                }
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}

function show_product_images(){
    global $post, $woocommerce, $product;

    echo '<div class="images lily-main-image">';

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $image_caption   = get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id() )->post_excerpt;
            $main_image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
            $image           = get_the_post_thumbnail( 
                $post->ID, 
                apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ), 
                array(
                    'title'           => get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ),
                    'data-zoom-image' => $main_image_link, 
                    'id'              => 'totemImgZoom'
                )
            );

            $attachment_count = count( $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids() );
            // echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<img width="320px"src="%s" id="totemImgZoom" data-zoom-image="%s" title="%s" alt="">', $main_image_link, $main_image_link, $image_caption), $post->ID);   
        }
        else {
        //  echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<img class="zoomImage" src="%s" alt="%s"/>', wc_placeholder_img_src(), __( 'Placeholder', 'woocommerce' ) ), $post->ID );
        }

        do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' );
        do_action( 'woocommerce_output_related_products');

    echo '</div>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution.

```html
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 25);
function woocommerce_output_related_products(){
 $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => 4,  
        'columns' => 4,  
        'orderby' => 'rand' 
 ); 
    woocommerce_related_products( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args', $args ) ); 
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer as works perfectly! One question @Javid is there a way to update the code so that related products only shows the linked images (without the add to cart and all the other default code? So that related products will just show the thumbnails?

Comment: @cchiera yes, this is possible, do you have this question on stack overflow. I'm little bit sick and take a look tomorrow morning